# Custom WCF fault error not working

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to get a WCF service to return a custom fault, so that the client knows what happened. Despite reading endless articles about how to do this, nothing works. Whatever I do, I get the generic "The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason" message.

I have tried the following...

```
throw new FaultException("It brok!");
```

...and have tried...

```
throw new FaultException<VrtSystemNotFoundException>(new VrtSystemNotFoundException());
```

...but the client only ever sees the standard FaultException.

Anyone any ideas what I'm doing wrong? In the client, I just wrap the service call in a try/catch block, and examine the exception.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 in case it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

From service behavior set

```
 <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />:
```

From the WCF service, throw the exception as shown below:

```
throw new Exception("Custom Exception");
```

At client side, you will get FaultException with message “Custom Exception”.

Note: In production, you have to keep includeExceptionDetailInFaults=”False” in order to restrict the service from sending sensitive information to client.

You can’t throw custom error messages as exceptions from a service. In order to throw custom error messages, you have to define a data contract type and throw that as a fault. See the following example.

```
[DataContract]
public class OrderFault
{
[DataMember]
public int OrderId { get; set; } 

[DataMember]
public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

In order to throw Fault to client, we have to specify the expected faults above the method/operation using the FaultContractAttribute as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(OrderFault))]
OrderType GetOrder(int orderId);
```

Now at client side, you have to catch the fault as follows:

```
catch (FaultException<OrderFault> ex)
{ 
}
```

Inside catch, you can get the exception details using ex.Detail. In our case, it's OrderFault.

That’s it. In this way, you can throw custom error message as fault from WCF service and use in client.

Note: Even if you throw fault from operation, if you don’t specify the expected Fault for the operation, at client side you will not get the fault.

The Message property of the FaultException is what is displayed on the error page so if it's not populated , you will see the 'The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason' message. To easily populate it, use the two parameter constructor when throwing the fault in the service as follows, passing your error message from your fault type as shown in the below example

```
InvalidRoutingCodeFault fault = new InvalidRoutingCodeFault("Invalid Routing Code - No Approval Started");  

throw new FaultException<InvalidRoutingCodeFault>(fault, new FaultReason(fault.ErrorMessage));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried all that. I started off using a regular Exception, and when that didn't work switche to a FaultException. I then tried the custom exception method, but I didn't copy all the code into my original question to save space. None of this worked, which is why I asked the question. I was doing exactly what all the articles I read said to do, but nothing worked. I tried with includeExceptionDetailInFaults false and true, and it also didn't make any difference. Any other ideas? Thx again

Comment: I just updated my answer can you please try again using that example in your code?

Comment: Nope, same problem. I even tried simplifying it and using a string... throw new FaultException<string>("Missing PCR number", new FaultReason("Missing PCR number")) but it didn't work. Still got the generic message in the client. I added [FaultContract(typeof(string))] to the service method. Any ideas? Thx again.

Comment: "The creator of this fault...." error. It was happening when I was debugging in VS2010. I found this post:

http://sergecalderara.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/systemservicemodelfaultexception1-was-unhandled-by-user-code/

which explained a couple of debugging options that I needed to turn off.  Please check

Comment: thx for the reply, but I think we're talking about different things. you're describing what happens in the server, I'm trying to get the exception in the client. Telling VS not to break in the server doesn't help me get the exception details in the client. Thx anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Ho hum. It turned out that the reason it wasn't working was that the WCF expert in our team had added a behaviour extension to the client, which enabled our service to send back more detailed exceptions. However, I was testing my code form a separate VS project, and didn't have this extra library referenced, so all the exceptions were being converted to a standard FaultException.

Once I added a reference to the library, and configured it in the test client's app.config, it worked fine.

The morla of the story is, if something should be working and isn't, check if anyone clever has done something clever and not told you!

Thanks to all who replied.